# How to use getSharedPreferences in a AppCompatActivity

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have a login class that extends `AppCompatActivity` but when I want to check my data and use `getSharedPreferences()` it has runtime error and will force stop! What should i do?

Here is my code:

```
package biz.test.internet;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.preference.PreferenceFragment;
import android.support.v4.content.SharedPreferencesCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;
import java.util.Random;

public class Login extends AppCompatActivity {
    SharedPreferences sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences(MyPREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.login);
    }        
}
```

Note that if i disable `SharedPreferences sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences(MyPREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);` then run time error will be fixed and if i use `PreferenceActivity` instead of `AppCompatActivity`, `setContentView` method will have error!

I don't know how to use both of them.

Thank you.

Comment: Can you please share the logcat error message ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to put the call *inside* your `onCreate` method.

```
SharedPreferences sharedpreferences;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.login);
    sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences(MyPREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
}
```

Comment: thankyou it works now , it was 3 hours i was seeking for it ! :) what was the reason ?

Comment: @Saeid Because you need a Context to get the pref which you have after onCreate.